# What will prevent LVN_ITEMACTIVATE from firing?

Tags: winapi, listview

I am writing an app with raw windows API (opensource Win32++) where I have a ListView.

The problem I have now is that whenever an item in the ListView is clicked, the system/app will generate a warning tone/sound "ding". Furthermore, I noticed I cannot get the LVN_ITEMACTIVATE through item-dbl-click or item-keypress-enter, which would normally work if this problem had not occur.

Would anyone have any idea how this might be happening?

I believe there is nothing wrong with Win32++, it just could be one of the things I do is causing this. But my program has become quite big to dissect plus I have no idea where to start looking.

Thanks.

PS: I had my computer muted for the longest time, hence, I don't know when this started eventhough I had the listview since a long time ago. T_T

Comment: Are you handling all the messages you're supposed to?

Comment: So you can select the items of your ListView, but you can't activate them? Does the `*ding*` sound occur when you select or when you try to activate an item?

Comment: @Lasse I am very certain I am already handling all messages correctly. WM_NOTIFY, LPNMHDR cast etc.

Comment: @Frederic For one, I am not sure what sequence of events consitute an "activate". But in another project, LVN_ITEMACTIVATE fires when i double-click on an item. The "ding" sound occurs on mousedown on an item. After that, the item is selected. So i guess i can select but cannot activate. NM_CLICK and NM_DBLCLICK works though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start looking with a tool that can show you the Windows messages that the control generates and receives.  Like Microsoft's Spy++.  Compare it with a working list view to have an idea what might be amiss.  Also check the parent window.  I haven't otherwise heard of listviews that dingaling, the LVN_ACTIVATEITEM should fire the first WM_LBUTTONDOWN, no double-click necessary.

Comment: sigh... still cannot figure out. there are just too many messages to look at.